# Kafka ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer stops consuming abruptly

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring kafka for consuming message using ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer , in production I am seeing it stops consuming the messages abruptly , without any errors , sometimes even a single consumer with the VM stops consuming while other consumers are still consuming (I have 15 partitions and 3 JVM , each has concurrency of 5).

When I restart the JVM , it starts consuming !!!

Is there anyway I can check periodically whether consumer had died or something and I can restart it without restarting the JVM !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the consumer thread is "stuck" in your code somewhere. I suggest you take a thread dump when this happens, to see what the thread is doing.

Comment: Hey Gary .... that's what I did and saw the consumer thread indeed in blocked state !! Next question how do we recover from this any suggestions ?

Comment: It depends on what it's blocked on. For example, if it's blocking trying to read from a socket, you can set a timeout on the socket (or close it to force an error).

Comment: Thanks Gary ..... the blocking thread is kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread .... I went through few threads in stackoverflow where people mentioned consuming of the messages stopped due to this thread being blocked ....not sure If that's the root-cause